# Create a table in Mysql from selected columns of exisiting table and with same structure

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a newbie and  i am using **mysql**. I want to create a table **product** from an existing table **customer** but i want only the selected columns of **customer** table to be created in new table and that too with the same structure. Eg In customer table there is a column with name **DATE** which has **default as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP** and **ON UPDATE CURRENT TIMESTAMP** . SO i want that this structure is also created in the new table.

I looked other answers but they do not copy the structure. Please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what you can do

1. use [`CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE old_table`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html) syntax to create a new table with the same structure
2. use [`ALTER TABLE new_table DROP COLUMN unnecessary_column`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html) syntax to drop unnecessary columns in the new table
3. use [`INSERT INTO new_table ... SELECT ... FROM old_table`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html) syntax to copy data

Let's say your `customer` table looks like

```
CREATE TABLE customer
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  name VARCHAR(5), 
  created DATETIME, 
  modified TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  other_column INT
);
```

And you want to create a new table `customer_new` but without `other_column`

```
CREATE TABLE customer_new LIKE customer;
ALTER TABLE customer_new DROP COLUMN other_column;
INSERT INTO customer_new (id, name, created, modified)
SELECT id, name, created, modified
  FROM customer;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f164/2)** demo

Comment: +1 Yes sir, it helped me  and there is no doubt about it.. Thank you for spending your valuable time. Your help is very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

USE THIS

```
CREATE TABLE NEW-TAB SELECT NAME,DATE FROM OLD-TAB;
```

Please change COLUMN/TABLE names as per your requirements

Comment: IT should. why don't you try and let us know.

Comment: sadly its not working bro :( . It is not copying the structure

Comment: well I just now tried it on mysql / mariadb , do not get any error

Comment: i am not saying that i am getting an error. i am saying that its not copying the structure. Its just copies the table name but not the default values etc

Comment: def value can not be copied , you will have to alter the column separately

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
create table product(DATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,ON UPDATE CURRENT TIMESTAMP );

INSERT INTO product (DATE,ON) SELECT DATE,ON FROM customer ;
```

OR

```
CREATE TABLE product  (DATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,ON UPDATE CURRENT TIMESTAMP )
       SELECT DATE,ON  FROM customer;
```

Comment: As far as i know data type cannot be copied,you can copy data from one table to  other using the above query.